# each function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*So what I try to do is the following:*
I got some items in 3 columns and default positioning (`position:static`). 
And I'm trying to **transition** them to `top:0; left:0` of the page.

---

Transitions between different positions (`absolute` and `static`) are not possible in CSS3, so I tried a jQuery workaround:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
  var items = $(this);
  $(this).css({
      'width': items.width(),
      'height': items.height(),
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': items.offset().top,
      'left': items.offset().left
  });
});
```

What this is supposed to do, is to take every item with class `item` and "duplicate" it at the exisiting position with `position:absolute`
This is working perfectly for one item. But as soon as I got multiple items, it simply stacks them at the position of the  first item...

---

Here's a fiddle:

```js
$(".item").each(function(){
  var items = $(this);
  $(this).css({
      'width': items.width(),
      'height': items.height(),
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': items.offset().top,
      'left': items.offset().left
  });
});
```

```css
#items{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
.item{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

My desired result is that jQuery takes every item, gets its position on the page, and replaces the CSS, so it's at the same position as before, just with `position:absolute`, so I can transition it to `top:0;left:0;` afterwards.

Comment: you are setting position to `absolute` that's why

Comment: What is the desired result? Currently you are setting each item to the position of top left corner. If `var items = $(this)` is supposed to refer to '#items', then you need to change it to `var items = $('#items')`.

Comment: So what are the expected results ? Where should each div be placed ?

Comment: @UsmanRana i guess you misunderstood my question. what i'm trying to do is to take every item `.item` and replace it with the same position and size and position absolute, so i can transition it to top, left: 0

Comment: @MarioA.Rawady The desired result is that jQuery gets the position of each item and replaces the CSS so it's `position:absolute` but at the same position, as if there was no javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always the same position if you use `absolute` ! Because you loop each item then apply it immediately so first div is changed to `absolute` and take it old position with `top,left` value .Then second div is not still change as absolute so it will also take `first div` position and duplicate with first div .This will continuing happen till loop end . So it all will have the same `top,left` value .

**So my solution is not to apply css property immediately , store value in one helper object and applied that all property after finished loop .**

```js
var beforeApply = {}
$(".item").each(function(){
  var items = $(this);
  beforeApply[$(this).index()] = {
      'width': items.width(),
      'height': items.height(),
      'position':'absolute',
      'top': items.offset().top,
      'left': items.offset().left,
      'text':items.text()
  };
});

for(var j in beforeApply) {
     var index = parseInt(j) + 1;
     var text = beforeApply[j].text;
    $("#items div:nth-child("+index+")").css(beforeApply[j]).text(text + "Changed position");
}
```

```css
#items{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
.item{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciated that !

Answer (score 0):

This "Transitions between different positions (absolute and static) are not possible in CSS3, so I tried a jQuery workaround:" can be worked around by having static by default, and then appending a class that has absolute. Then the CSS attribute "transition" will work.

fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/nikoimp/vL9bahra/

```
$("#1").addClass('1');
$("#2").addClass('2');
$("#3").addClass('3');
$("#4").addClass('4');
$("#5").addClass('5');
    #items{
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 10px;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }
    .item{
        -webkit-transition: width 2s;
        transition: width 2s;
        width:100%;
        height:20px;
        text-align:center;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0 0 10px 0;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .1 {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
    }
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="items">
      <div class="item" id="1">1</div>
      <div class="item" id="2">2</div>
      <div class="item" id="3">3</div>
      <div class="item" id="4">4</div>
   <div class="item" id="5">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You simply pass `position:absolute` through jQuery... I could have done that  simply with CSS aswell. And of course transitions will work then because its  _from absolute to absolute_ and not _from static to absolute_ which I want to do.

Comment: you want "from static to absolute" ? then have static as default and addclass with jQuery that has absolute? :p mby i dont understand the question, can you specify more?

Comment: ahh i se your desired at the bottom now, this is also doable in the same manner, you would just have to create 5 css classes that are styled to same position, but with position:absolute, and append those like in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, I could manually position the items with `position:absolute`, but like this it would be waaaay more difficult to handle the responsiveness...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I was able to find is to append the new content in another hidden div, then remove the old div, and show the new one.

You was facing that problem, because while updating the `divs` to position absolute, the other `divs` styling was also being updated at the same time because they are floating.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".item").each(function(){
    var items = $(this);

    var _text = items.text() ;
    var _css = "width:" + items.width() + "px" + 
        "; height:" + items.height() + "px" + 
        "; position:absolute" +
        "; top:" + items.offset().top + "px" + 
        "; left:" + items.offset().left + "px" + ";"
    var _style = "style='" + _css + "'" ;

    var _div = "<div class='item' " + _style + ">" + _text + "</div>" ;

    $("#items_clone").append(_div) ;
  });
  
  $("#items").remove() ;
  $("#items_clone").show().attr("id", "items") ;
}) ;
```

```css
#items{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
#items_clone{
  display:none;
}
.item{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<div id="items_clone">

</div>
```